# Pass values on validation

Tags: node.js

Till now when I used to validate an input form in POST router in nodejs , I would use res.redirect. But this causes all the values from the form to clear.

Is it a good practice if I use again in POST router, res.render and pass the values like that to the inputs?

I ask on the long run.

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: I don't need help with the code , I just asked for an advice.